# Why does glmnet.py throw a TypeError at cvglmnet when I provide floats, if glmnet does require floats?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to run a glm for logistic regression using Glmnet package for python following Glmnet Vignette and I am having problems with the type of my response variable 'y'.
I want to perform both the glmnet function and the cvglmnet function. The vignette says that "For binomial logistic regression, the response variable y should be either a factor with two levels, or a two-column matrix of counts or proportions.".
I got my y values from one column of a pandas dataframe. Similarly my input matrix x is from several columns of a pandas dataframe. So my y.values is a numpy.ndarray of shape (290,) made of 1's and 2's, so an array of integers.

To check my types, if I do:

```
isinstance(y.values,scipy.ndarray)
True
isinstance(y.values,np.ndarray)
True
isinstance(y.values,int)
False
type(y.values[1])
numpy.int64
isinstance(y.values, float)
False
```

If I run

```
fit = glmnet(x = fold1_sp.copy(), y = y.values, family = 'binomial')
```

I get an error

```
ValueError: y input must be a scipy float64 ndarray
```

I found in https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python/issues/15 that they tried to address this issue mentioning that any search for scipy float 64 ndarrays returns numpy float ndarray results because they are basically the same object type, so I convert to numpy float:

```
fit = glmnet(x = fold1_sp.copy(), y = np.float64(y.values), family = 'binomial')
```

and it runs just fine.
But this way my y array is made of floats 1.'s and 2.'s

If I now try using the cvglmnet function, it complains it needs an integer

```
cvfit = cvglmnet(x = fold1_sp.copy(), y = np.float64(y.values), family = 'binomial', ptype = 'class')
```

throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

which is strange at least to me since it asked for a float before, and if I use my y as integers using the original y.values, then it complains again it needs scipy float64.

So how can I overcome this TypeError problem?.

Thanks ever so much

Comment: I found there is an issue in the github repository for glmnet_python that is apparently closed without the problem being solved.
https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
cvglmnet(x = fold1_sp.copy(), y = np.int64(y.values), family = 'binomial', ptype = 'class')
```

Comment: No @MLS, it throws similar error message:
    
    `ValueError: y input must be a scipy float64 ndarray`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem but with X data, and I solve it by putting

```
cvglmnet(x=X.astype(np.float64), y=y,family = "gaussian",alpha=1)
```